# Tkinter Scrollbar Freeze GUI

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas

The purpose of this project is to load all the file names and a download button to download the files from the URL which is provided by the user.

I have a python script that runs but when I press the down arrow to scroll results the **GUI freezes.**  I would like to resolve this issue so that the GUI does not freeze when the down arrow is pressed.

I am very new to python so have probably made some beginner mistakes

This is a python GUI using tkinter and chromedriver.exe

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as font
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome,ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from threading import Thread
import webbrowser
import time
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("640x480")
root.state("zoom")

tk.Label(root,text="URL:",font=font.Font(size=20)).place(x=20,y=20)
url_input = Entry(root,font=font.Font(size=20))
url_input.place(x=20,y=60,width=490,height=40)

global result_frame
urls = []

main_frame = LabelFrame(root)

canvas = tk.Canvas(main_frame, highlightbackground="gray")
canvas.pack(side=LEFT,fill="both",expand="yes")

v_scroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(main_frame,orient="vertical",command=canvas.yview)
v_scroll_bar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill="y")

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=v_scroll_bar.set)
canvas.bind("<Configure>",lambda e : canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

result_frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
result = []
result_b = []

canvas.create_window((0,0),window=result_frame,anchor="nw")
main_frame.pack(fill="both",expand="yes")

def download_links(links) :
    global result_frame
    global urls
    urls = links
    for l in links :
        lLabel = tk.Label(result_frame,font=font.Font(size=20),text=str(links.index(l)+1)+"."+l.find_elements_by_css_selector("*")[0].get_attribute("title"))
        lLabel.grid(row=links.index(l),column=0,sticky=tk.W)

        lDownloadB = tk.Button(result_frame,text="Download")
        lDownloadB.grid(row=links.index(l),column=1,sticky=tk.E,ipadx=10,ipady=5)
        def dl(e) :
            durl = "https://ps4.td-index.workers.dev/0:down/_Alvro%20Collection/"+urls[result_b.index(e.widget)].find_elements_by_css_selector("*")[0].get_attribute("title")
            print(durl)
            webbrowser.open_new(durl)
        lDownloadB.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",lambda e : dl(e))

        result.append(lLabel)
        result_b.append(lDownloadB)
        main_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=1)
        canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=1)
def res () :
    while True :
        time.sleep(0.0000000001)
        canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
t = Thread(target=res)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

def scrap() :
    global d
    if not url_input.get().strip().replace("\n","") == "" :
        options = Options()
        options.headless = True
        d = Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe",options=options)
        d.get(url_input.get())
        def func() :
            time.sleep(2)
            while True :
                time.sleep(0.00001)
                links = d.find_elements_by_css_selector("#app > div > section > div > div > div.golist > table > tbody > tr")
                if len(links) > 50 :
                    t = Thread(target=lambda:download_links(links))
                    t.daemon = True
                    t.start()
                    break
                else :
                    d.refresh()
        t = Thread(target=func)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        print(d.find_elements_by_css_selector("#app > div > section > div > div > div.golist > table > tbody > tr"))

scarp_b = tk.Button(root,text="Get",font=font.Font(size=20),command=scrap)
scarp_b.place(x=510,y=60,width=100,height=40)

def conf() :
    url_input.place(x=20,y=60,width=root.winfo_width()-150,height=40)
    scarp_b.place(x=root.winfo_width()-120,y=60,width=100,height=40)
    main_frame.place(x=0,y=140,width=root.winfo_width(),height=root.winfo_height()-140)
root.bind("<Configure>",lambda e : conf())
root.mainloop()
```

When run this script it looks like.

When i input this link( [Please copy this link](https://ps4.td-index.workers.dev/0:/_Alvro%20Collection/) ) and press **GET** button it will delay for a moment or two, then display data. But when I try to press the down arrow the entire GUI freezes.

[GUI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Shn.png)

Now Its time to press **GET** Button:
you can see this video its not working.

[Youtube Link](https://youtu.be/ARK1USFDCVk)

Comment: It's already minimal reproducible code. Scrollbar Not working when the data is present in LabelFrame.

Comment: there is no use for `res()` function, so You can remove it. Basically everything from `def res()` until including `t.start()` can be deleted (the first `t.start()` after `def res()`), that is also what probably is causing the issue, because You don't allow the canvas to do anything, it just gets reconfigured. Why there is no need for this? You already have bound canvas to `"<Configure>"` event which is called pretty much every time the canvas gets changed, so for example if the frame got bigger because of multiple labels it would call this event and reconfigure the scrollregion

Comment: Thanks it's working now.

Comment: You should bind `"<Configure>"` on `result_frame` instead of  `canvas` because adding items to `result_frame` will not change the size/position of `canvas` and so `"<Configure>"` event will not be triggered on `canvas`.